# iframe not working for some sites

Tags: html, iframe

I tried to access some sites using iframe. Seems it works for some sites but not for others. Any ideas about this? How to fix it? The src link in the iframe is valid, I can access it directly. It just didn't show up in the iframe.

Is this related to X-Frame-Options? How to go around it?

Thanks a lot.

========

Here is the html codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>IFrame Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="http://s.click.taobao.com/t?e=zGU34CA7K%2BPkqB07S4%2FK0CITy7klxn%2F7bvn0ay1PXvKwtZSEswjTW0qipvZgGECAqg4jFMvRrmqEsewCV2vrDIKlj1m7fQBXl8oXaLeyNdntQSWHx%2F4LzcWUbay3v1DbpVnqVPkubyxNIXPljUBoBNuLFC0ZLm4SV46zTasP3e6uSYcfiqrWYSyZV%2B7G&spm=2014.21191910.1.0" width="100%" height="600" >
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what sites work and what don't? Are they in the same domain? Also, be more specific about what "doesn't work" means. We aren't sitting at your computer so we need a lot of information to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Is this related to X-Frame-Options?**

Yes, well kinda. It's difficult, possibly impossible, to determine what technique was adopted on the server side to prevent contents from being loaded in frames of different domains, but the `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` wasn't used. This are response headers returned, when attempting to load the web page in question in an iframe:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Tengine
Date: Sun, 27 Jan 2013 06:24:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Location: [too long, irrelevant, removed ;)]
Expires: Sun, 27 Jan 2013 06:24:22 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

As you can see, the server responds with HTTP status code 302 (`moved temporarily`), which is often used on web servers instead of `forbidden` in a bid to prevent any additional such requests overloading the web server (or to distinguish individual denied requests one from another in log files). However, there isn't any `X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN` header. Such header might or might not be respected by various browsers anyway.

> **How to go around it?**

Not doing some illegal and nasty work on the web server involved, or knowing what conditions need to be satisfied for web server to grant access to the requested location, that's impossible to say. You could ask the admin of the web server kindly to make an exception to this rule for your domain, though. Just a thought...

**EDIT**: Upon further investigation, the URL you provided actually redirects to

`http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13188785766&ali_trackid=2:mm_32761976_0_0:1359267664_4k8_1456591680&spm=2014.21191910.1.0`

meaning there are some server-side rewrite rules involved. That doesn't help you much with your URL, but you could use the one it translates to, if all you wanted is to present the target page to the end user. Problem is, you lose any session data and/or tracking cookies that you might have wanted to force on the unsuspecting user and collect spoils of some referral scheme. I'm not implying that's what you wanted to do, but if you did, putting in the iframe source a translated URL wouldn't work. ;)